# My button onClick process doesn't work in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My other `buttons` are working while this `button` just doesn't work.

Here is a snippet of my codes:

```
 public class RegisterActivity : Activity
{
    EditText txtfullname;
    EditText txtaddress;
    EditText txtusername;
    EditText txtpassword;
    EditText txtconfirmpass;
    Button btncreate;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.registerPage);

        txtfullname = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextFullname);
        txtaddress = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextAddress);
        txtusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextUsername);
        txtpassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextPassword);
        txtconfirmpass = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextConfirmPassword);
        btncreate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonRegister);

        btncreate.Click += Btncreate_Click; //this doesn't get process even though I have an onclick of it

    }
```

Comment: does it work now ?

Comment: Yes. the issue is there is no AppcompatActivity in my activity. I had the event handler and everything before that. I debugged it myself. Thank you for your concern kind sirs

Answer (score 1):

first make sure `Resource.Id.buttonRegister` is your button's Id

second you have created the `EventHandler` :

```
btncreate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonRegister);
btncreate.Click += Btncreate_Click;

private void Btncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //do something when click the button
  }
```